# Rails says class is nil despite console showing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, web, null

I have a database of objects (tools) in my Ruby on Rails project.  When I use "rails dbconsole" and

```
select * from tools;
```

it returns a whole list of tool objects.  But when I try to view the following page, it gives me an error.

Page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<%= stylesheet_link_tag "tools", :media => "all" %>
<body>
<%= @tools.each do |tool| %>
 <%= link_to(tool(image_tag.image_url)) %>
 <% end %>

</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

When I change the code to add an if statement against nil objects, the page works (without displaying any tools).

```
<% if @tools.nil? %>
<% else %>
  <%= @tools.each do |tool| %>
    <%= link_to(tool(image_tag.image_url)) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So it seems like @tools doesn't have any values in it, but when I look at it in the dbconsole, there are tools there.  I can't figure this out, and I've spent the past few days googling for answers, so any and all ideas would be welcome!

EDIT: Added tools_controller.rb

```
class ToolsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :check_authentication
def check_authentication
  unless session[:user_id]
    session[:intended_action] = action_name
    session[:intended_controller] = controller_name
    redirect_to new_session_url
  end
end

  def new
    @tool = Tool.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @tool }
    end
  end

 def show
 end

 def index
    @tools = Tool.all
  end

  # GET /tools/1/edit
  def edit
    @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /tools
  # POST /tools.json
 def create
    @tool = Tool.new(params[:tool])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tool.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tool, :notice => 'tool was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @tool, :status => :created, :location => @tool }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @tool.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please include your controller code, which is probably the source of the problem.

Comment: I've added the controller code.  Thanks!

Comment: "But when I try to view the following page" <- which view are you talking about here? If it's for the `index` view then this should work, since you are correctly assigning `@tools = Tool.all`. If it is any other view then it won't work.

Comment: The page is localhost:3000/show.  When I type that in, it gives me the error.

Comment: Then the problem is that you are not loading `@tools` in your show action. You can do as @nbarraille has suggested and load this into every action, but are you sure that's what you want? Do you need the full list of tools in every page? If not then you shouldn't do that, because it will hit your DB every time you visit any page.

Comment: How would I load it only in the show action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `@tools` variable to be accessible from your view, you need to declare it in your controller, like this:

```
@tools = Tool.all
```

If you want it to be only accessible from one page, just declare it in the according method.

Here is an example, assuming you want to make the variable available for your `home/index` page:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @tools = Tool.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
    end
  end
end
```

If you want it to be accessible in all your pages, you can declare it in the `before_filter` method of your `ApplicationController`.

Here is how to do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :load_variables

  # Load variables to be used everywhere
  def load_variables
    @tools = Tool.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks like it took care of that issue, thanks! But then another error pops up:
'  
Showing G:/1000Tools/app/views/tools/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Extracted source (around line #9):

6: <body>
7: 
8:   <%= @tools.each do |tool| %>
9:     <%= link_to(tool(image_tag.image_url),tool) %>
10:     <% end %>
11: </body>
12: </html>

'
(Sorry, still trying to figure out style for comments.)

Comment: That means that on line 9: (`<%= link_to(tool(image_tag.image_url),tool) %>`), you are calling with 0 arguments a ruby method which was defined with 1. Please take a look at this guide: `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html`

Answer (score 2):

Loading `@tools` in a before_filter for *every* action as @nbarraille has suggested is a bad idea, because there are many (probably most) actions where you will *definitely* not need the full set of tools (e.g. `create` and `destroy`). The line `@tools = Tool.all` hits your database so you should minimize the number of times you use it.

For the case you have here, you only need to change your `show` action to get this to work:

```
def show
  @tools = Tool.all
end
```

However, note that normally the `show` action is for displaying a *single* resource (tool), not the whole list of resources (which is normally done in the `index` action). It looks like you're deviating from the normal way of doing things, is there any particular reason why?

Comment: Yep, there's a very particular reason: I'm a noob and don't know what I'm doing.  :D  But I'll change it to index now that I know that.

Comment: Surround the text in backticks (`). About the actions/views, it's a good idea to go through the rails documentation and see what the conventions are. Rails is all about conventions, and if you deviate from them you should be sure there is a good reason for it.

Comment: Ah, okay, I was trying to use apostrophes.  And thanks for the tip - I'll be sure to check them out before I do much more coding.